# right shift >> turns value into zero javascript

Tags: javascript, bit

Trying some bit manipulation in javascript.

Consider the following:

```js
const n = 4393751543811;
console.log(n.toString(2)) // '111111111100000000000000000000000000000011'
console.log(n & 0b11) // last two bits equal 3
const m = n >> 2; // right shift 2
// The unexpected.
console.log(m.toString(2)) // '0'
```

The result is 0? The expected output I am looking for after the right shift is:

```
111111111100000000000000000000000000000011 // pre
001111111111000000000000000000000000000000 // post >>
```

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Javascript bitwise operators are on 32bit.

Comment: Is there anything else in the standard ECMAScript library that can be used to accomplish the result?

Comment: try console.log(n | 0b11) it will return also 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript bitwise operators on numbers work "as if" on 32bit integers.

`>>` (sign-propagating right-shift for numbers) will first [convert to a 32-bit integer](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toint32). If you read linked spec, note specifically

> Let int32bit be int modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.

In other words, all bits above 32 will simply be ignored. For your number, this results in the following:

```
111111111100000000000000000000000000000011
┗removed━┛┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━32bit━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

If you want, you can use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```js
const n = 4393751543811n; // note the n-suffix
console.log(n.toString(2))
console.log(n & 0b11n) // for BigInt, all operands must be BigInt
const m = n >> 2n;
// The expected.
console.log(m.toString(2))
```

The [spec for `>>` on `BigInt`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-bigint-signedRightShift) uses `BigInt::leftShift(x, -y)`, where it in turn states:

> Semantics here should be equivalent to a bitwise shift, treating the BigInt as an infinite length string of binary two's complement digits.